# django catching all URLS under a specific name

Tags: django, django-urls

I'd like to have one entry under urls.py that'll catch all sub-folders in a URL starting with a particular folder, `example` in this instance:

example:

```
/business
/business/one
/business/one/two
/business/one/two/three
/business/one/two/three/four
```

I want all those URLS to go a **single** **view**, where I can later determine how many levels of folders there are after `/business/` and their names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`<path:…>`** path converter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters), but this requires the element to be non-empty.

## using `re_path`

If you thus want to match paths including empty ones, you can make use of the `([^/]+/)*` regex pattern:

```
from django.urls import re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^business/(?P<path>([^/]+/)*)$', views.myview, name='myview'),
]
```

and then in the view split the path:

```
def myview(request, path):
    path_items = path.split('/')
```

`path_items` is than a list of path elements.

## Custom *path converter*

You can also register a custom path converter:

```
# app/converters.py

class EmptyPathConverter:
    regex = '([^/]+/)*'

    def to_python(self, value):
        return value.split('/')

    def to_url(self, value):
        return '/'.join(value)
```

and then register the path converter and use it when defining a path:

```
from app.converters import EmptyPathConverter
from django.urls import path, register_converter

register_converter(EmptyPathConverter, 'emptypath')

urlpatterns = [
    path('business/<emptypath:paths>', views.myview, name='myview'),
]
```

then we can use this in a view, which will already do the splitting for us:

```
def myview(request, paths):
    # paths is a list of strings
    # …
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but I am forced to end my endpoint URL with `/` in order to avoid the Django error about APPEND_SLASH. Is there a way around it?

Comment: @JasonGenX: yes, use `r'^business(?P<path>(/[^/]+)*)$`, so here we prepend the slash to each "path" chunk. Then however using `path.split('/')` will return the empty string as first item, if the `path` is non-empty.

Comment: can i use this method to redirect all urls in my app to new url of the app?Does that keep my seo?